# app.post won't work, expressJS

Tags: node.js, rest, express, server

I want to integrate a button on my website that will open a port, recieve some data, update a database and then render the home page. Basically I need that botton to execute the code between the app.post's curly brackets.
That works fine when I click the button for first time but then, after rendering, I have to restart the server to do that again.

```
app.post('/test', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {

port.on('data', function (data) {

  sirDeAfisat+=data.toString('ascii');
    if(checker.sfarsitSir(data)==true) {

          if(checker.sirOk(sirDeAfisat)==true){
              fs.appendFile("./log/date.txt",sirDeAfisat,(err)=>{
                if(err) console.log(err.message);
              });
              const child=fork('./parser_ok.js');
              child.send(`${sirDeAfisat}`);
              child.on('message',(answ)=>{
                console.log(`Sunt portul, am primit de la parser : ${answ}`)
                child.kill('SIGINT');
              });
          }else{
                  fs.appendFile('./log/erori.txt',new Date().toISOString(),function (err){
                    if(err) console.log(err.message);
                  }); 
                  fs.appendFile('./log/erori.txt',"SIR !OK",sirDeAfisat,(err)=>{
                    if(err)  console.log(err.message);
                  });
          }
      sirDeAfisat='';
        port.close();
        res.send(201);
        return;
    }
});

port.on('readable',() =>{
    port.read();
});
});
```

isLoggedIn:

```
function isLoggedIn (req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
}

res.redirect('/');
}
```

and this is test.ejs

```
   <!-- form -->
        <form action="/test" method="post">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">
        </form>
```

Comment: but it works one time....

Comment: Can you include the `isLoggedIn` function in your question ?

Comment: Sure, i will include

Comment: @Seblor `app.post()` takes an argument of a query path and then as many callbacks as you want, as long as they have a middleware signature. This is clearly indicated in the documentation: "app.post(path, callback [, callback ...])
... Callback can be one function, multiple functions..."

Comment: @JSilv Ah my bad. I will remove my comment. Thanks for correcting me.